# Creating a TRX raw transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tron

I want to create a raw transaction (without signing it) and get its hash in hex format. The official TRON API normally returns a JSON for [creating transactions](https://developers.tron.network/reference/walletcreatetransaction). Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: It seems TRON's wallet-cli can generate it but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the api with your transaction details abd get transaction back

```
const data = {
        to_address: toHex(to),
        owner_address: toHex(from),
        amount: amount,
    };
let transaction = await tronWeb.fullNode.request('wallet/createtransaction', data, 'post');
```

Comment: It returns to me in JSON format. I want the transaction to be in hex.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you need the raw hex representation of not signed transaction.
For this purpose you can use the tronweb library, they have APIs to create TRX, trc10 or token transfer transaction and return both JSON and hex representation:
https://developers.tron.network/v3.7/reference/sendtrx

Here it the example from the mentioned docs:

```
tronWeb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx("TVDGpn4hCSzJ5nkHPLetk8KQBtwaTppnkr", 100, "TNPeeaaFB7K9cmo4uQpcU32zGK8G1NYqeL");
```

returns

```
{
    "visible": false,
    "txID": "9f62a65d0616c749643c4e2620b7877efd0f04dd5b2b4cd14004570d39858d7e",
    "raw_data": {
        "contract": [
            {
                "parameter": {
                    "value": {
                        "amount": 100,
                        "owner_address": "418840e6c55b9ada326d211d818c34a994aeced808",
                        "to_address": "41d3136787e667d1e055d2cd5db4b5f6c880563049"
                },
                    "type_url": "type.googleapis.com/protocol.TransferContract"
                },
                "type": "TransferContract"
            }
        ],
        "ref_block_bytes": "0add",
        "ref_block_hash": "6c2763abadf9ed29",
        "expiration": 1581308685000,
        "timestamp": 1581308626092
    },
    "raw_data_hex": "0a020add22086c2763abadf9ed2940c8d5deea822e5a65080112610a2d747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e5472616e73666572436f6e747261637412300a15418840e6c55b9ada326d211d818c34a994aeced808121541d3136787e667d1e055d2cd5db4b5f6c880563049186470ac89dbea822e"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create raw_data_hex,It need a raw_data.proto protocol to convert:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package YourPackageName;
option java_package = "wallet.core.jni.proto";


message Contract {
    enum ContractType {
        AccountCreateContract = 0;
        TransferContract = 1;
        TransferAssetContract = 2;
        VoteAssetContract = 3;
        VoteWitnessContract = 4;
        FreezeBalanceContract = 11;
        UnfreezeBalanceContract = 12;
        WithdrawBalanceContract = 13;
        UnfreezeAssetContract = 14;
        TriggerSmartContract = 31;
        FreezeBalanceV2Contract = 54;
        UnfreezeBalanceV2Contract = 55;
        WithdrawExpireUnfreezeContract = 56;
        DelegateResourceContract = 57;
        UnDelegateResourceContract = 58;
    }
    ContractType type = 1;
    message Parameter {
         message Transfer {
                bytes owner_address = 1;
                bytes to_address = 2;
                int64 amount = 3;
         }
         string type_url = 1;
         Transfer value = 2;
    }
    Parameter parameter = 2;
}


message raw_data_hex {
    bytes ref_block_bytes = 1;
    bytes ref_block_hash = 4;
    int64 expiration = 8;
    repeated Contract contract = 11;
    int64 timestamp = 14;
}

message signRaw_data_hex {
    raw raw_data = 1;
    repeated bytes signature = 2;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful, rather than just posting a code snippet, to explain the solution, to help others utilise this in their own use-cases.